# asp.net ashx handler: can't receive response

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, ashx

Hello everyone and thanks for your time.
Here is my javascript:

```
$('.sender').click(function (e) {       
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "fHandler.ashx",
        data: { firstName: 'stack', lastName: 'overflow' },
        // DO NOT SET CONTENT TYPE to json
        // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
        // DataType needs to stay, otherwise the response object
        // will be treated as a single string
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert('error: ' + response);
            console.log('err: '+response);
        }
    });                    
});
```

And here is the code in my `.ashx` handler:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");//to fix the allow origin problem
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    string json = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
    context.Response.Write(json);
}

public bool IsReusable
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

While the click event is working, my `Ajax`request doesn't seem to get any response as the alert at success doesn't popup. I've debugged using the browser's network console and it return the expected response but it doesn't seem to reach the success function in the `JavaScript` code. Any insights or suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: a single string isn't valid json. Adding an error handler would help. Also inspect requests in network tab of browser console for clues

Comment: I have edited my post, I still can't get that alert to pop up. However the posts do send back 200 response statuses.

Comment: Got it to work after changing dataType: "text"

Answer (score 1):

In case you are still interested in the answer, try this before doing the request

```
var data = { firstName: 'stack', lastName: 'overflow' };
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
```

and change your AJAX request to

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "fHandler.ashx",
    data: jsonData,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset-utf-8'
})
.done(function (response) {
    // do something nice
})
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("request error");
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(errorThrown);
});
```

**Explanation**

You are trying to send the plain `data` object. You must transform it into a Json string using `JSON.stringify(object)`.

Changing the dataType isn't really a solution but a workaround.

**Additional Notes**

Also, I think you should use `.done()` and `.fail()`. [See here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for further details.